# Should you pass a whole object as a single prop or split it into smaller parts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Assume I've got a component that is responsible for displaying a timeline item containing various data (id, label, type, timestamp, etc). When coming to render this component, what is the standard for the props?
Do I pass through the timelineItem object as a prop and deconstruct it within the component?

E.g.

```
({ timelineItem }) => {
  const { id, label, timestamp, type } = timelineItem;

  return ...
};

// Render
<TimelineItem timelineItem={timelineItemObject} />
```

Or alternatively, is it advised to split out the object outside of that component?
E.g.

```
({ id, label, timestamp, type }) => {
  return ...
};

// Render
<TimelineItem id={id} label={label} timestamp={timestamp} type={type} />
```

I believe there can be performance benefits for splitting up the props into smaller chunks so that React can perform prop diffs better however take my code below. I've got two components that receive mostly the same props (As the group is mostly only responsible for displaying chunks of timeline items) and I'm unsure what structure to use for readability/maintainability

[image: Lots of props]

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: I do not think there is any significant performance difference between the two.

However, from a readibility point, you should consider passing the whole object.
Otherwise your `return` will become large, which is not so readable with let's say 10 props.

Answer (score 0):

A props diff is performed by value on primitive types (number, string, boolean) and by reference on objects. So passing an object as props is faster than passing all of the properties of this object

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, since ’timeline’ is being passed in and mapped for any change in timeline, the TimeLine items will be updated and rerendered anyway

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would pass an entire obj and create an interface for it. In most general cases I would say breaking up props makes your app easier to read and scale.